# Profile.Get in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How do I get Profile valueof anybody(Profile.Age,Profile.Name) when the user is not logged in?

Comment: How do you know who the user is if they are not logged in?

Comment: i have:http://www.mysite.com/user.aspx?username=Raj

i want get all information from Profile value of Raj...

Comment: if you don't have some type of username/password then pretty much anyone can access the user information.  personally, i would never use any site that does not take care for my privacy.

Comment: All of the comments above this are clueless. Truth.

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

```
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(username,true);
var age = (int)profile.GetPropertyValue("Age");
```

Comment: @kenom - glad to help and welcome to stackoverflow. I did my job in helping you, now your job is to click the 'up' arrow over the '0' next to my answer to indicate that you like it, and then click the checkmark to indicate that it solved your problem.